# Create log-normal on y axis?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I currently have a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBk80.jpg) with log numbers on the x-axis and the y-axis goes from 0-100. How can I get it to I guess log normal y-axis as shown in the picture below? Thank you for your help!

[image]